# Select2 directive callback when rendering done

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ui-select2, angularjs-select2

I want to trigger a callback or event when my [`ui-select2`](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#doc-query) directive

```
<input
    type="hidden"
    ui-select2="myConstructorObject"
    ng-model="myModel"
    required />
```

has rendered the Select2 DOM elements. How can I achieve this? Is there any constructor atrribute I am not aware of?

Comment: What type of task are you trying to solve  with calling a callback specifically after the directive is rendered ?

Comment: I want to bind a click event handler on the `ul` that is being rendered.

Comment: You mean the ul of the dropdown items ? And that thing gets re rendered each time the dropdown is opened. I see there are "select2-opening" and "select2-open" events which can be used to capture that http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/ Does that help ?

Comment: Yes it helped. I added a directive to the select2 element which listens to the `select2-loaded` event. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI, I achieved it by adding a directive to the select2 element which listens to the `select2-loaded` event. This event is fired when the DOM object is completely initiated.